# Entity-Framework-Core: Mapping 1 to 1 Relationships using Composite Keys

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm having difficult configuring a 1:1 mapping in EntityFrameworkCore using FluentAPI.  The navigational reference is always NULL.  The only obvious difference between my code and countless others I have examined is I am trying to map via composite keys.

I've played around using annotations instead of Fluent API but encounter the same issue described in my summary.

## Class Definitions

```
[Table("SomeTable")]
public class Defect
{
    [Column("Record")]
    public int DefectId { get; set; }
    [Column("insp_id")]
    public int InspId { get; set; }
    [Column("defectnum")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public virtual Simulation Simulation { get; set; }
}


[Table("SomeSimulationTable")]
public class Simulation
{
    [Column("Record"), Key]
    public int SimTableId { get; set; }
    [Column("insp_id")]
    public int InspId { get; set; }
    [Column("DefectNumber")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [Column("SimulationName")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Column("SimulationAlgorithm")]
    public string Algorithm{ get; set; }

    public virtual Defect Defect { get; set; }
}
```

## Fluent API (in OnModelCreating)

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Defect>()
     .HasKey(h => new { h.InspId , h.Number });

 modelBuilder.Entity<Defect>()
     .HasOne<Simulation>(p => p.Simulation)
     .WithOne(i => i.Defect)
     .HasForeignKey<Simulation>(b => new { b.InspId , b.Number });
```

When the "Defect" class is populated through the dbContext all data is available; however, when I attempt to access the "Simulation" property of the "Defect" class I encounter the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I have also verified there is valid data in our database where the "Defect" should have a "Simulation".

Any help?  Throwing myself at the mercy of other coders....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Include` method when loading from the database, it will be null unless you explicitly load:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-2.1
- https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-include-theninclude